# How to merge the results of two divergent xpaths for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sql-server-2016

I'm new at this so please bear with me. I have two select statements containing all the information that I want from an XML document in Microsoft SQL Server 2016. I want combine the contents of these two select statements and then turn it into a table. The problem is that the xpath diverges. I am not sure what to do.

Here is my first query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/roll/bill', 1)
WITH (
[where] char(5) '../@where',
[session] tinyint '../@session',
[year] smallint '../@year',
roll smallint '../@roll',
[datetime] datetime '../@datetime',
number int)
```

Here is my second query:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/roll/voter', 2)
WITH (
    id int '@id',
    [value] char(50) '@value',
    [state] char(2) '@state',
    [category] char(7)'../category',
    [type] varchar(1000)'../type',
    [question] varchar(1000)'../question',
    [result] varchar(20)'../result')
```

Here is a baby-sized version of my xml document:

```
<roll where="house" session="114" year="2015" roll="705" source="house.gov" datetime="2015-12-18T09:49:00-05:00" updated="2016-12-25T10:03:32-05:00" aye="316" nay="113" nv="5" present="0">
<category>passage</category>
<type>On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566</type>
<question>On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566: H R 2029 Making appropriations for military construction, the Department of Veterans Affairs, and related agencies for the fiscal year ending September 30, 2016, and for other purposes</question>
<required>1/2</required>
<result>Passed</result>
<bill session="114" type="h" number="2029" />
<option key="+">Yea</option>
<option key="-">Nay</option>
<option key="P">Present</option>
<option key="0">Not Voting</option>
<voter id="412607" vote="+" value="Yea" state="NC" />
<voter id="400004" vote="+" value="Yea" state="AL" />
<voter id="412615" vote="+" value="Yea" state="CA" />
<voter id="412625" vote="+" value="Yea" state="GA" />
</roll>
```

I would appreciate it if someone could show me exactly what I need to do as well as an explanation of why.

[Here is a screenshot of my two select statements and their results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQRtv.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How is it that you want the columns from your statements to be combined? For example, since your first statement returns 1 row and your second one returns many rows, perhaps you want the columns from your first statement to appear on every row with the columns from the second statement. You could do that thusly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/roll/bill', 1)
WITH (
[where] char(5) '../@where',
[session] tinyint '../@session',
[year] smallint '../@year',
roll smallint '../@roll',
[datetime] datetime '../@datetime',
number int)
,OPENXML (@hdoc, '/roll/voter', 2)
WITH (
    id int '@id',
    [value] char(50) '@value',
    [state] char(2) '@state',
    [category] char(7)'../category',
    [type] varchar(1000)'../type',
    [question] varchar(1000)'../question',
    [result] varchar(20)'../result')
```

Result:

```
where    session     year    roll    datetime                    number      id          value   state   category    type                                                                                question                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    result
house    114         2015    705     2015-12-18 14:49:00.000     2029        412607      Yea     NC      passage     On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566      On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566: H R 2029 Making appropriations for military construction, the Department of Veterans Affairs, and related agencies for the fiscal year ending September 30, 2016, and for other purposes    Passed
house    114         2015    705     2015-12-18 14:49:00.000     2029        400004      Yea     AL      passage     On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566      On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566: H R 2029 Making appropriations for military construction, the Department of Veterans Affairs, and related agencies for the fiscal year ending September 30, 2016, and for other purposes    Passed
house    114         2015    705     2015-12-18 14:49:00.000     2029        412615      Yea     CA      passage     On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566      On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566: H R 2029 Making appropriations for military construction, the Department of Veterans Affairs, and related agencies for the fiscal year ending September 30, 2016, and for other purposes    Passed
house    114         2015    705     2015-12-18 14:49:00.000     2029        412625      Yea     GA      passage     On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566      On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566: H R 2029 Making appropriations for military construction, the Department of Veterans Affairs, and related agencies for the fiscal year ending September 30, 2016, and for other purposes    Passed
```

As long as your first statement returns only one row, this will give you the same number of rows as your second statement. If your first statement would return 2 rows and your second 4, this would return 8 rows: all combinations of rows from the first table and rows from the second table. This is known as a *cross join*.

If you expect more than 1 row from each statement and there is some definite way to correlate rows from each statement together, then you want an *inner join*.

I'm going to stop here, as it seems likely that you know a little bit about SQL and are just confused about how XML works in it. But if you need more info, say so in the comments and I'll try to expand the answer.

Comment: Thankyou! This is exactly what I wanted. You are right that I am very inexperienced in SQL but the words cross join and inner join are actually familiar to me. I just didn't make the connection because I was too fixated on the XML. Am I right in thinking that for crossjoin it doesn't matter which comes first but for inner join it does? Also, if I was working with SQL tables and not xml the name of the tables would take the place of OPENXML right?

Comment: Also wouldn't a crossjoin and innerjoin yield the same results no matter what in the case of my data?

Comment: The order does not matter for inner join either; it's symmetric. The only joins that are not symmetric are LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN. An inner join would return fewer rows if the join condition made it do so. For example, if the first query had a state column, joining on State=State would mean you'd only get rows where the states were the same. In your particular data you've shown here though, there are no matching columns, so an inner join is impossible.

Comment: And yes, the table names would go in place of the OPENXML expression if you were working with tables.

Comment: Thankyou for the clarification!

Comment: This is no good suggestion! `FROM OPENXML` is outdated. And so is your oldfashioned join with comma-syntax. This approach was okay with SQL Server 2000, but OP states version 2016... Futhermore, there's no need to dive down to `/roll/bill`, just to use slow backward navigation (`../@where`)...

Comment: @Shnugo: then feel free to edit my answer so it meets your SQL standards. Or propose one of your own. A downvote is quite unfriendly.

Comment: I responded to the question asked by the user; I didn't attempt to update his XML work. If the comma really bothers you then just edit it and replace it with CROSS JOIN or whatever syntax you feel is warranted. I find comma joins very simple to understand and I do not know of any reason they should be avoided other than style.

Comment: (his or her ... not sure of gender, since "ana ng" is a song title and clearly a pseudonym)

Comment: @RossPresser, I would edit an answer to correct a typo, but not in order to re-write it completely... A downvote is not unfriendly, but marks an answer as *not usefull*... Well, you may cut a tree with a pocket knife... But if somebody asks you for help with this, you should show him a chain saw, rather than suggest to sharpen his pocket knife. Sorry, I did not want to be unfriendly...

Comment: About *comma join*: Try to use the value of the table before the comma in a later context and then replace the comma with `CROSS JOIN`. See the difference?

Answer (score 2):

`FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used anymore... (rare exceptions exist). Better use the *real XML methods*. Try this:

I'm assuming, that the upper part of the XML is *meta-data* and the `<voter>`elements are `1:n`-related *work-data*. Therefore my result returns with one row per voter. I hope I got this correctly!

```
DECLARE @DummyTable TABLE(YourXML XML);
INSERT INTO @DummyTable VALUES
(
N'<roll where="house" session="114" year="2015" roll="705" source="house.gov" datetime="2015-12-18T09:49:00-05:00" updated="2016-12-25T10:03:32-05:00" aye="316" nay="113" nv="5" present="0">
  <category>passage</category>
  <type>On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566</type>
  <question>On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566: H R 2029 Making appropriations for military construction, the Department of Veterans Affairs, and related agencies for the fiscal year ending September 30, 2016, and for other purposes</question>
  <required>1/2</required>
  <result>Passed</result>
  <bill session="114" type="h" number="2029" />
  <option key="+">Yea</option>
  <option key="-">Nay</option>
  <option key="P">Present</option>
  <option key="0">Not Voting</option>
  <voter id="412607" vote="+" value="Yea" state="NC" />
  <voter id="400004" vote="+" value="Yea" state="AL" />
  <voter id="412615" vote="+" value="Yea" state="CA" />
  <voter id="412625" vote="+" value="Yea" state="GA" />
</roll>'
);
```

--The query

```
SELECT --first level attributes
       r.value(N'@where',N'nvarchar(max)') AS roll_where
      ,r.value(N'@session',N'int') AS roll_session
      ,r.value(N'@updated',N'datetime') AS roll_updated

      --first level elements
      ,r.value(N'(category)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS category
      ,r.value(N'(type)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [type]
      ,r.value(N'(result)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS result

      --second level attributes
      ,r.value(N'(bill/@session)[1]',N'int') AS bill_session

      --named choice    
      ,r.value(N'(option[@key="+"])[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS option_plus
      ,r.value(N'(option[@key="-"])[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS option_minus
      ,r.value(N'(option[@key="P"])[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS option_P
      ,r.value(N'(option[@key="0"])[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS option_0

      --it seems to be, that your "voter" elements are a 1:n related list?
      --therefore I used a second CROSS APPLY with .nodes() to get them row-wise
      ,v.value(N'@id','int') AS voter_id
      ,v.value(N'@vote','nvarchar(max)') AS voter_vote
      ,v.value(N'@value','nvarchar(max)') AS voter_value
      ,v.value(N'@state','nvarchar(max)') AS voter_state
FROM @DummyTable AS dt
CROSS APPLY dt.YourXML.nodes(N'roll') AS A(r)
CROSS APPLY A.r.nodes(N'voter') AS B(v)
```

The result

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| roll_where | roll_session | roll_updated            | category | type                                                                           | result | bill_session | option_plus | option_minus | option_P | option_0   | voter_id | voter_vote | voter_value | voter_state |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| house      | 114          | 2016-12-25 15:03:32.000 | passage  | On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566 | Passed | 114          | Yea         | Nay          | Present  | Not Voting | 412607   | +          | Yea         | NC          |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| house      | 114          | 2016-12-25 15:03:32.000 | passage  | On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566 | Passed | 114          | Yea         | Nay          | Present  | Not Voting | 400004   | +          | Yea         | AL          |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| house      | 114          | 2016-12-25 15:03:32.000 | passage  | On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566 | Passed | 114          | Yea         | Nay          | Present  | Not Voting | 412615   | +          | Yea         | CA          |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| house      | 114          | 2016-12-25 15:03:32.000 | passage  | On Concurring in Senate Amdt with Amdt Specified in Section 3(a) of H.Res. 566 | Passed | 114          | Yea         | Nay          | Present  | Not Voting | 412625   | +          | Yea         | GA          |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```